# Scala: Code coverage for projects with tests in separate modules

Tags: scala, test-coverage

For a variety of admin reasons, our projects have the following structure:

```
someproject-core
someproject-api
someproject-test
```

The idea is all the tests are in a separate module.

**Question:** What plugin can I use to get accurate test coverage?

Comment: Did you find a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Scoverage: https://github.com/scoverage/sbt-scoverage
It supports multi-module SBT projects and measures statement coverage instead of line or branch coverages.

BTW there is a nice plugin for Sonar to browse coverage reports:
https://github.com/RadoBuransky/sonar-scoverage-plugin

Comment: Is there an SBT 0.12.x version of scoverage? I'm not able to resolv 0.98.x against sbt 0.12.x.

Comment: No there isn't. When I wrote the plugin I needed some functionality that 0.12 doesn't support although I cannot remember what that is.

Comment: Unfortunately Scoverage doesn't support tests that are in a different module to code because of the way it instruments the code.

If you try it you'll find that you get 0% coverage.